# drop down nav not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have designed a website and it works fine in all browser but IE, I have used a template nav bar and put it in as a stylesheet for my nav bars through out my website, but when i view it in internet explorer the child elements of the parents appear off to the left side of the browser, so far they go off the viewers window. I have tried to fiddle with the css code but nothing seems to work, i tried changing the position and getting rid of position absolute in the nav bar coding which made the elements appear on the page but they were all over the place.

**CSS:**

```
/* The outermost container of the Menu Bar, an auto width box with no margin or padding */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: default;
    width: auto;
    color: #ed3694;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/* Set the active Menu Bar with this class, currently setting z-index to accomodate IE rendering bug: http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html */
ul.MenuBarActive
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
/* Menu item containers, position children relative to this container and are a fixed width */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal li
{
    margin: 0.1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 8.6em;
    float: right;
    visibility: visible;
}
/* Submenus should appear below their parent (top: 0) with a higher z-index, but they are initially off the left side of the screen (-1000em) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    margin: 0.1;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    z-index: 1020;
    cursor: default;
    position: absolute;
    width: 191px;
    left: -1000px;
    height: 111px;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 34px;
    }
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to auto so it comes onto the screen below its parent menu item */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: -52px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
/* Menu item containers are same fixed width as parent */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li
{
    width: 8.6em;
}
/* Submenus should appear slightly overlapping to the right (95%) and up (-5%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: -5% 0 0 95%;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to 0 so it comes onto the screen */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left:auto;
    top: 0;
}
```

Webpage to view source code: [www.mopowered.co.uk](http://www.mopowered.co.uk)

If anyone can help i would be so grateful. I just need to get it working right in IE.

Tanya

Comment: it would be great if you could put up your problem/example/question on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the parent `li` with class `MenuBarItemIE` in ie takes `position:static`. If you change it to `position:relative` will move the content under the `li` element (not perfectly as ff for example but much better. If you dont know what is the problem let me know).

Comment: Hey,kinda unsure of what you mean, u talkign about the source code or the css.

Comment: @Tanya there is an inline css in ie only for some reason. This creates the problem

Comment: ps i could be being stupid but you mean ie does a incline css for you even though i did not put it there, how is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

The Spry Menu js library you are using has a lot of issues (do a quick google search). Maybe you should consider using something else.

But I was able to get a quick and dirty fix by commenting/deleting out the following lines in SpryMenuBar.js

```
        if(Spry.is.ie)
        {
            this.addClassName(items[i], this.isieClass);
            items[i].style.position = "static";
        }
```

I don't think this is the right solution, but it seems to work in your case.